# WCF RESTful service with varyByParam and UriTemplate

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching

I'm having trouble getting caching to work using varyByParam when I'm also using UriTemplate for a RESTful WCF Service.  The varyByParam behaves correctly when I use normal query string parameters however.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{appId}/CacheTest/{param}")]
[WebCache(Duration=300, VaryByParam="param")]
string CacheTest(string appId, string param);
```

All CacheTest does is return the current time.  I call it with the following combinations: `/1/CacheTest/1`, `/2/CacheTest/1`, `/1/CacheTest/2`, `/2/CacheTest/2`.  Each call returns a different time.

When I do this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
[WebCache(Duration=300, VaryByParam="param")]
string CacheTest(string appId, string param);
```

Both `/CacheTest?appId=1&param=1` and `/CacheTest?appId=2&param=1` return the same time. The same is true for `/CacheTest?appId=1&param=2` and `/CacheTest?appId=2&param=2`.

How can I make the first case behave like the second case?  I tried VaryByCustom, but I don't have access to the parameters inside my GetVaryByCustomString unless they are in the query string.